# How to visualize frequency distribution table?

Tags: data-visualization

I have a table that has this structure. So as you see, the frequency of each subset is identified in each cell. It's very unclear which one is better.

```
    COC EG EE AC LE ME SC
 CE   3 22  0  0  4  3 50
 AU  21  7  1  0  0  0 15
 WA   4  0 10  0 12  0 21
 HH   0 12  5  0  2  1  8
 MH   0  2  0  2  2  0 26
 HA   8  7  3  0  1  0  8
 TY   0  0  0  0  0  0  1
 PK   3  0  0  0  0  0  2
 SR   0  1  0  0  0  0  1
 FU   0  0  0  0  0  0  2
```

To import directly into R:

```
library(gsheet)
data <- read.csv(text = gsheet2text('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RHFifBQpuia_YXtSogjv0j9pkNLL6WMR9sRN78VGR4k/edit?usp=sharing',
format ='csv'), row.names=1)
```

To make this a bit more human readable, I could use heatmap style. That means higher the number, the darker the color of the cell.

Are there are any better solutions?

Comment: Please post that in a form that can be copied and pasted into people's favourite software. Are the rows and columns already in an order that makes substantive sense? (I can't identify what they mean, which may be deliberate.)

Comment: Many relevant threads here, e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147721/which-is-the-best-visualization-for-contingency-tables http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56322/graph-for-relationship-between-two-ordinal-variables

Comment: To underline my last question, it's important to know whether rows and columns can be permuted without loss of meaning.

Comment: The number 21 on the cell shared between AU on a row and COC on a column means there are 21 papers published in AU in the field of COC. I just need ideas on how to plot it so the data itself won't be that important.

Comment: Stacked charts might be a way.

Comment: @Ashalynd could be but I'm sure there is better. Any more ideas?

Comment: Sure, you want ideas, but the whole point of posting in a forum is that the answers could interest many different people. Therefore, being able to use your example would make answers more vivid to many readers. Personally, I decline to type in 70 numbers. It's the responsibility of the OP to make a question publicly interesting and not just a way to get individual help in public.

Comment: @NickCox, all I wanted is a general chart scrapped from the internet to use in order to make this data look more readable; not a customized chart made by someone herefor this data. That would be so generous but not so needed to answer the question.

Comment: It's good that you found what you wanted. Other people will, or will not, upvote your question and answer on whether either appears generally useful.

Comment: I modified your table because enough effort has been poured into this question not to get an answer, but I completely agree with @Nick Cox comments.

Comment: @l'ombradel'atzavara, it was awfully nice of you to spend your time typing all that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sankey Diagrams did a great job as an alternative to visualize this frequency table.

Sankey diagrams look similar to this [image]

So with each item in the row, a line should go to the corresponding item in the column. The width of the line should be proportional to the value inside the common cell between row and column.

While this image has three or more levels of change, the frequency table above should have two levels only. The left level should represent row items and the right level should represent the column items.

Photo credit goes to Mike Bostock. The photo was taken from a creative commons article written by Tony Hirst too. More details could be found [here](http://blog.ouseful.info/2012/05/24/f1-championship-points-as-a-d3-js-powered-sankey-diagram/).

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. We try to avoid overly brief or [link-only answers](/stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) (which are subject to link-rot and [may be deleted](/stats.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)). At present this is more of a comment than an answer in its own right. If you're able, could you expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link. Alternatively we can convert it into a comment for you.

Comment: @Glen_b better?

Comment: If you can legally post the diagram (e.g. if it falls under a creative commons license, or is in the public domain), you'll need to give credit in order to conform to the SE rules on such posting as well as conform to whatever rules the license itself imposes. If that's a diagram you own the rights to it won't be necessary to give credit

Comment: @M-T-A If you managed to create a similar plot with your data, can you please include it in your response, together with an explanation of the variables and the code you used, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Try MATLAB: put your table as input and it will generate a heatmap for you.

see https://plot.ly/matlab/heatmaps/

Comment: Tha'ts not what I'm asking for. I just want other ideas (other than heatmaps) to plot this.

Comment: Not sure your purpose. I may use stacked bar chart (each bar represents a country or a research domain). This kind of chart can clearly show the dominant research area of each country.