# Chart suggestions for data flow

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2, sankey-diagram

I am working on a project in R using the General Social Survey that charts the numbers of one religious group who convert to another (Catholic $\rightarrow$ Evangelical, Evangelical $\rightarrow$ None, None $\rightarrow$ Catholic, Catholic $\rightarrow$ None, etc.). I'd like to create a graphic representation of this showing the relative sizes of the populations that are making these shifts. Currently I'm using a stacked bar chart but it is difficult to read. Is there a better chart to show the flow of data from one state to another?

code for data set

```
Region  <- rep(c('Midwest'),9)
RELIG16 <- rep(c('Protestant','Catholic','None'),3)
OutRel  <- rep(c('Protestant'), 3) 
OutRel  <- append(OutRel, rep(c('Catholic'),3))
OutRel  <- append(OutRel, rep(c('None'),3))
value   <- rep(c(77.35, 10.25, 18.18),3)
df      = data.frame(Region, RELIG16, OutRel, value)

ggplot(df, aes(x=RELIG16, y=value, fill=OutRel)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  xlab("Original Religious Affilliation") + ylab("Percentage") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Conversion\nType",
                  # breaks=c("protestant.prop", "catholic.prop", "none.prop"),
                  labels=c("to Protestant", "to Catholicism", "to None")) +
  ggtitle("Conversion of All Millennials By Region")
```

Comment: [SO] is a site for help w/ `R` code. If you want to know what type of graph is appropriate for a certain type of data, you should ask on [stats.SE] (the SE site for statistics, data visualization, etc.). If you wait, we will try to migrate this for you. In the interim, it would help if you could provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536).

Comment: You might take a look at chord plots: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708674/network-chord-diagram-woes-in-r

Comment: I would also investigate a sankey diagram and suggest `riverplot`

Answer (score 4):

Your data are a little odd to me.  I'm guessing that `value` is intended to be the proportion of members of a given religion who were believers in the `RELIG16` religion previously.  I tweaked the numbers so they added up to 100%.

```
Region  <- rep(c('Midwest'),9)
RELIG16 <- rep(c('Protestant','Catholic','None'),3)
OutRel  <- rep(c('Protestant'), 3) 
OutRel  <- append(OutRel, rep(c('Catholic'),3))
OutRel  <- append(OutRel, rep(c('None'),3))
value   <- c(77.35, 15.25, 7.4)[c(1:3,2,1,3,2,3,1)]
df      = data.frame(Region, RELIG16, OutRel, value)
df
#    Region    RELIG16     OutRel value
# 1 Midwest Protestant Protestant 77.35
# 2 Midwest   Catholic Protestant 15.25
# 3 Midwest       None Protestant  7.40
# 4 Midwest Protestant   Catholic 15.25
# 5 Midwest   Catholic   Catholic 77.35
# 6 Midwest       None   Catholic  7.40
# 7 Midwest Protestant       None 15.25
# 8 Midwest   Catholic       None  7.40
# 9 Midwest       None       None 77.35
```

Since your data are flows, I agree with @JakeKaupp that a [Sankey diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram) is most appropriate.  I further agree about using the [riverplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/riverplot/index.html) package in R.  There are [various packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9968433/1217536) for making Sankey diagrams in R (although I am not familiar with a `ggplot2` version), but I am most familiar with riverplot.  Here is an example Sankey diagram with your (modified) data:

```
library(riverplot)
eg = data.frame(N1=rep(letters[1:3], times=3), 
                N2=rep(letters[4:6], each=3), 
                Value=df$value)
nd = data.frame(ID=letters[1:6], x=rep(1:2, each=3), labels=df[1:6,2])
rp = makeRiver(nodes=nd, edges=eg, node_styles=list(
                   a=list(col="red"), b=list(col="yellow"), c=list(col="blue"), 
                   d=list(col="red"), e=list(col="yellow"), f=list(col="blue") ))
windows(height=4, width=7)
  plot(rp, plot_area=.7, gravity="bottom")
  title(main="Transitions between Religions", line=-1.5)
```

[image]

---

If you had a matrix with the actual numbers of people in each combination of before and after religious preferences, you could use standard methods for visualizing contingency tables, such as [mosaic plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_plot) or possibly [correspondence analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/147868/7290).